# Why SAP Business One SDK uses double for money?

Tags: sapb1

I always read that I should use `decimal` or similar for money and financial calculations ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when)). However as much I can see, all of the Business One SDK uses `double`s? Is this okay? Am I expected to convert the double values to decimals every time I am doing calculations, than back to double If I want to set it for an API object (what I do currently)?

[image]

Note: The SQL database uses `numeric(19,6)` for these values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite what it might look like in Visual Studio, the SAP SDK isn't really a .Net-native library - it's a .Net wrapper over a C/C++ dll using COM Interop.

I don't think that `decimal` is a native type in C/C++, and it's certainly not a basic/intrinsic type in .Net (unlike e.g. `string`, `int`, `double`, etc) - it's also slower to use because there's no intrinsic CPU instructions for Decimal operations (unlike the basic types).

Because there's no equivalent in C/C++, it would have to be translated to a type that can be understood by the underlying library - and that type would likely be `double` anyway.